# Android - How can I prevent view focus changes?

Tags: android, android-layout

I´d like to implement something like a "beforeLosingFocus" event to my controls (EditText) and I want to be able to prevent the focus changes so my control must have the focus until the user type allowed values.

I tried to use onFocusChange event but this event is fired after the focus changes.
This event is fired two times (because one control lost the focus while another control get it).

Is possible to prevent that another control get the focus in a generic way? 
(because the focus can change by a tap in another control or a "Next" key click)

Answer (score 2):

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener {
    ...
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
            return true // if you want to ignore IME_ACTION_NEXT
            return false // if you want to lose focus and go further
        }
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you can do this:
1) keep all the other views's `setFocusable` property to **false** by default. Then enable them as per your logic, one by one.

2) When `onFocusChangedListener` is called, set the focus back to the view you want using `v.requestFocus()` .

Comment: First way: it breaks the navigation through the Next key.
Second way: the focus blinks in the next control and the keyboard of the next control is shown.

Comment: As soon as user enters something, make other views focusable. As written in the question, you want to prevent focus changes until the users input something.

Answer (score 0):

Override your EditText's OnFocusChangeListener with for "in activity" changes *and* override the navigation buttons' OnClicks to perform an integrity test.

**EDIT** 
(It helps if I proof read, sorry)

You mentioned that know how to override the `onFocusChange(View view, boolean state)` in your EditText to *force* the user to enter text by checking `if(state == false)`. But you also discovered, when the user clicks a navigation button (like Next) the onFocusChange is *never* called before starting a new activity.

So keep the onFocusChange if you have more than one EditText (for example username and password) *and* add a check inside your Next button's onClickListener to verify that the user has entered text in your EditText *before* you start a new activity.

Comment: I did not understand your suggestion. What do you mean by "override your EditText's OnFocusChangeListener with for "in activity" changes"?